# How to access my AWS S3 Bucket in angular using syncfusion file manager?

Tags: node.js, syncfusion, file-manager

I am trying to access my s3 bucket and show the photos in my angular using the syncfusion file manager.

in my TypeScript file:

```
ajaxSettings:any;

  public hostUrl: string = 'http://localhost:3000/';
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ajaxSettings = {
    url: this.hostUrl + 'api/v1/upload/'
```

in my html:

```html
<ejs-filemanager id='default-filemanager' [ajaxSettings]='ajaxSettings'></ejs-filemanager>
```

and here is my server.js in my NodeJS API:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post('/api/v1/upload/', upload.array('image', 1), (req, res) => {
res.send({ image: req.file });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`server started on port 3000`);
});
```

and I have a JS file for uploading photos to AWS S3:

```
aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    accessKeyId: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: 'ap-south-1'
   });
   
   const s3 = new aws.S3();
   const upload = multer({
   storage: multerS3({
    acl: 'public-read',
    s3,
    bucket: 'angular-upload-files-2023-2024',
    key: function(req, file, cb) {
      req.file = file.originalname;
      //include the folder created before uploading files...
      cb(null, "properties2023/" + file.originalname);
     }
    })
   });

   module.exports = upload;
```

I am struggling how to connect to S3 bucket from my html going through my NodeJS?

```html
<ejs-filemanager id='default-filemanager' [ajaxSettings]='ajaxSettings'></ejs-filemanager>
```